# Does Aurora have any EVM, MetaMask and WEB3 support on NEAR protocol?

Tags: aurora-evm, aurora-near

Do you have any EVM, MetaMask and WEB3 support on NEAR protocol?

Answer (score 0):

It does, Aurora is a smart contract on NEAR Protocol with an EVM inside. It also  provides a full ETH RPC interface and has ETH as a base token. The whole idea is to just change the name of the network to Aurora Testnet or Mainnet in the existing ETH smart contract and deploy. Of course you can also add Aurora to MetaMask easily. Either manually, or by clicking the connect MetaMask button while on the Rainbow bridge.